# Past a variable in a text box

Tags: javascript, text, numbers, web, applescript

I don't know how to do this. I vaigate a lot on the forum and outside but I i can't solve it.
I want to put te text that is contened inside "IVA" variable in to a Text-Box on a website.
I search the id of the text-box and is: f1:j_idt144

This is the final part of the code:

```
   tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    set a to "A"
    set b to "B"
    set c to "C"
    set d to "D"
    set e to "E"
    set f to "F"
    set y to "1"
    repeat 5 times
        tell application "Numbers"
            activate
            tell table 1 of sheet 1 of document 1
                --display dialog a & y
                set y to y + 1
                set az to a & y
                set bz to b & y
                set dz to d & y
                set ez to e & y
                set fz to f & y
                set the selection range to cell az
                copy value of cell az to IVA
                copy value of cell dz to CF
                copy value of cell ez to import
                copy value of cell fz to intestatario
                copy value of cell bz to giorno
                display dialog IVA & " , " & CF & " , " & import & " , " & intestatario & " , " & giorno
                delay 1
            end tell
        end tell
        tell application "Safari"
            activate
            do JavaScript "document.getElementsById('f1:j_idt144')[0].click();" in document 1
            delay 1
            tell the application "System Events" to keystroke IVA
            delay 2
        end tell

    end repeat
    -- attivare
    display notification "FINISHED" sound name "Glass" with title "#Tag Liker"
end tell
```

Comment: Did you try filling the text field using JavaScript only?

Comment: mmm I don't know java script...  you know how to do with java script?

Comment: do JavaScript "document.getElementsById('f1:j_idt144')[0].value='dateon a cell of excell';" in document 1

Comment: ah no the problem is that IVA is a variable because it changes every time. I can write:
do JavaScript "document.getElementsById('f1:j_idt144')[0].value={IVA};" in document 1  ???

Comment: `set iva to "xxx"`

`set javascriptString to "document.getElementsById('f1:j_idt144')[0].value='" & iva & "';"`
`do JavaScript javascriptString in document 1`

Comment: mm i don't understand... i will correct the question and i will put the full code, so you can help me. I need to set IVA because the program need to set the variable froma excell cell!

Comment: added as an answer. try replacing `tell safari` code with that.

Comment: Why are you saying "excel" when your code is clearly using "Numbers"!?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set javascriptString to "document.getElementsById('f1:j_idt144')[0].value='" & IVA & "';"
    do JavaScript javascriptString in document 1
    delay 1
    tell the application "System Events" to keystroke IVA
    delay 2
end tell
```